# How to create sorted list of Pages in Octopress or Jekyll?

Tags: ruby, jekyll, octopress, jekyll-extensions

I have a Octopress website, which has posts and pages. Now I want to add another category of pages which I want to call as `writepus` ( notes which I will keep updating like a wiki  via git commits).

I want to keep these notes in a folder called `_notes`, just like we have `_posts` in `source` folder of Octopress.

I have a folder called `_writeups/` with files such as:

```
subject1.html
subject2.html
```

I have a file called `notes/list.html` with following content.

```
---
layout: page
navbar: Notes
title: Notes
footer: false
---

<div id="blog-archives">
{% for post in site.writeups reverse %}
{% capture this_year %}{{ post.date | date: "%Y" }}{% endcapture %}
{% unless year == this_year %}
  {% assign year = this_year %}
  <h2>{{ year }}</h2>
{% endunless %}
<article class="page-header">
  {% include archive_post.html %}
</article>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

Basically I want to create a listing of these writeups so that I can keep updating them as and when I get time. Also I want to keep these separate from `posts` and `pages`.

How can I achieve this functionality using Octopress / Jekyll ?

Answer (score 1):

Jekyll version 2, which has only recently been released, has the ability to have extra [collections](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/) and [data](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/datafiles/). Collections is probably what you are looking for, so upgrade your version of Jekyll and visit http://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/ to find out more about them.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. Let me setup newer version and try it out.